# Android Room Database Ignore Problem "Tried the following constructors but they failed to match"

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack, android-database

**My entity class:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
    var name: String,  
    var age: Int,   
    var gpa: Double,
    var isSingle: Boolean,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0,    

    @Ignore                           //don't create column in database, just for run time use
    var isSelected: Boolean = false                     
)
```

And then I insert like this (tested in `androidTest`):

```
val student = Student("Sam", 27, 3.5, true)

studentDao.insert(student)
```

It gives me this error right after I added the `@Ignore` annotation:

```
C:\Android Project\RoomTest\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\roomtest\database\Student.java:7: ����: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class Student {
         ^
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
  Student(java.lang.String,int,double,boolean,boolean,long) -> [param:name -> 
matched field:name, param:age -> matched field:age, param:gpa -> matched 
field:gpa, param:isSingle -> matched field:isSingle, param:isSelected -> 
matched field:unmatched, param:id -> matched field:id][WARN] Incremental 
annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the 
following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor 
(DYNAMIC).
```

Comment: What is "it" in "It gives me this error"? Is this a compile-time build failure or a runtime crash? If it is a runtime crash, please post the entire stack trace!

Comment: @CommonsWare it's a compile-time build failure.

Comment: There should be more to it, though, than just that line. Could you post more of the build output around this line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Room still generates Java-classes during compile and the problem is with default-valued parameter, try to use [@JvmOverloads](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation) for constructor:

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student @JvmOverloads constructor(
    var name: String,
    .....
```

**UPDATE**

It's interesting that [here in documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#ignore) there is no mentioning of special treatment to this case. And [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154420356) already exists to fix this documentation.

From [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70762008) as for the problem itself conclusion is:

> Using @JvmOverloads should work. One day in the not-so-distant future we might generate Kotlin and this won't be an issue

Comment: You're amazing!

Comment: Also, I find out that the `@PrimaryKey` part should be placed at the end of the constructor, otherwise it will cause error.